# Choose between android.app.AlertDialog and android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is there any guideline, on when should we use `android.app.AlertDialog`, or when should we use `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`?

As, both work equally well for me, if my min SDK is `android:minSdkVersion="14"`.

Answer (score 1):

`android.app.AlertDialog` has a visual [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37008457). Using the `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` solves it.